# How to define multiple name tags in a struct

Tags: json, struct, go

I need to get an item from a mongo database, so I defined a struct like this

```
type Page struct {
    PageId string                 `bson:"pageId"`
    Meta   map[string]interface{} `bson:"meta"`
}
```

Now I also need to encode it to JSON, but it encodes the fields as uppercase (i get PageId instead of pageId) so i also need to define field tags for JSON. I tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
type Page struct {
    PageId string                 `bson:"pageId",json:"pageId"`
    Meta   map[string]interface{} `bson:"meta",json:"pageId"`
}
```

So how can this be done, define multiple name tags in a struct?

Answer (score 373, accepted):

What you need to do is to use space instead of commas as tag string separators.

```
type Page struct {
    PageId string                 `bson:"pageId" json:"pageId"`
    Meta   map[string]interface{} `bson:"meta" json:"meta"`
}
```

It says in the [documentation of the `reflect` package](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructTag):

> By convention, tag strings are a concatenation of optionally space-separated key:"value" pairs. Each key is a non-empty string consisting of non-control characters other than space (U+0020 ' '), quote (U+0022 '"'), and colon (U+003A ':'). Each value is quoted using U+0022 '"' characters and Go string literal syntax.

Comment: Also, make sure it is separated only by a space, not by a tab. cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215510/cannot-retrieve-id-value-using-mgo-with-golang

Comment: It would be awesome to make it match both:  [bj]son:"pageId"

Answer (score 97):

Thanks for the accepted answer.

Below is just for the lazy people like me.

**INCORRECT**

```
type Page struct {
    PageId string                 `bson:"pageId",json:"pageId"`
    Meta   map[string]interface{} `bson:"meta",json:"pageId"`
}
```

**CORRECT**

```
type Page struct {
    PageId string                 `bson:"pageId" json:"pageId"`
    Meta   map[string]interface{} `bson:"meta" json:"pageId"`
}
```