# Golang multiple json tag names for one field

Tags: json, go, struct, tags

It it possible in Golang to use more than one name for a JSON struct tag ?

```
type Animation struct {
    Name    string  `json:"name"`
    Repeat  int     `json:"repeat"`
    Speed   uint    `json:"speed"`
    Pattern Pattern `json:"pattern",json:"frames"`
}
```

Comment: Voting to re-open. The question linked as duplicate with answer is for assigning multiple *different* name tags in a struct. The OP is asking for how to assign multiple `json` tags... which is a different question.

Comment: Dup, see good answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37118263/is-it-possible-to-have-a-struct-with-multiple-json-tags

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See [How to define multiple name tags in a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18635671/how-to-define-multiple-name-tags-in-a-struct/18635910) on how you can define multiple tags on one struct field.

You can also use a `type Info map[string]interface{}` instead of your struct.

Or you can use both types in your structure, and make method `Details()` which will return right pattern.

```
type Animation struct {
    Name    string  `json:"name"`
    Repeat  int     `json:"repeat"`
    Speed   uint    `json:"speed"`
    Pattern Pattern `json:"pattern"`
    Frame   Pattern `json:"frames"`
}

func (a Animation) Details() Pattern {
    if a.Pattern == nil {
        return a.Frame
    }
    return a.Pattern
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I needed something like this for retro compatibility. This is good.

Comment: I think this is a good answer, but IIUC you *cannot* use multiple json name tags to any useful effect. For example `json:"pattern" json:"frames"` will **not** tell `Unmarshal` to unmarshal either `pattern` or `frames`. So maybe it's worth noting after the link "but this doesn't work the way you want"

Answer (score 20):

you can use multiple json tag with third part json lib like `github.com/json-iterator/go`
coding like below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/json-iterator/go"
)

type TestJson struct {
    Name string `json:"name" newtag:"newname"`
    Age  int    `json:"age" newtag:"newage"`
}

func main() {

    var json = jsoniter.ConfigCompatibleWithStandardLibrary
    data := TestJson{}
    data.Name = "zhangsan"
    data.Age = 22
    byt, _ := json.Marshal(&data)
    fmt.Println(string(byt))

    var NewJson = jsoniter.Config{
        EscapeHTML:             true,
        SortMapKeys:            true,
        ValidateJsonRawMessage: true,
        TagKey:                 "newtag",
    }.Froze()

    byt, _ = NewJson.Marshal(&data)
    fmt.Println(string(byt))
}

output:

    {"name":"zhangsan","age":22}
    {"newname":"zhangsan","newage":22}
```

Comment: Your solution answers for when somebody wants to add multiple different tags to different packages. ie in your case json and newtag. OP asked for a usecase when he/she wants to target the same package. ie. In json if you have to specify 2 different properties. Usecases for example in  json formatting options, ORMs etc. Your solution is pretty much just working around that problem. no?

Comment: Is there any pkg for yaml ?