# JSON unmarshal does not output in my code, works in goplayground

Tags: json, go

After reviewing several questions, I have decided to ask my question.  A few things I can say...

- The struct I am inserting json data into is exported, and so are its fields.
- The struct I am inserting json data into was auto-generated by protoc.
- The struct and code I am using works in goplayground https://goplay.space/#WZWs3dsVcR5

The code I have is broken into a few parts.

protofile message defining the QueryParm struct.

```proto
message QueryParm {
  string column_name = 1;
  string column_type = 2;
}
```

My struct in `protobuf.pb.go`

```golang
type QueryParm struct {
    ColumnName           string   `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=column_name,json=columnName,proto3" json:"column_name,omitempty"`
    ColumnType           string   `protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=column_type,json=columnType,proto3" json:"column_type,omitempty"`
    WhereValue           string   `protobuf:"bytes,3,opt,name=where_value,json=whereValue,proto3" json:"where_value,omitempty"`
    XXX_NoUnkeyedLiteral struct{} `json:"-"`
    XXX_unrecognized     []byte   `json:"-"`
    XXX_sizecache        int32    `json:"-"`
}
```

My data in `pg_client.go`

```golang
type PgData struct {
    ...
    QueryParms   string    `orm:"null"`
    ...
}
```

And my function in grpc_client.go

```golang
func createJobResponse(d *pg.PgData) (*pb.JobResponse, error) {
    var qp []*pb.QueryParm

    if d.QueryParms == *new(string) {
        d.QueryParms = "[{}]"
    }
    fmt.Printf("Parms: %v\nType: %T\n", d.QueryParms, d.QueryParms)
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(d.QueryParms), &qp); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    fmt.Printf("Parms: %v\nType: %T\n", qp, qp)
    return &pb.JobResponse{
        ...
        QueryParms:   qp,
        ...
    }, nil
}
```

The output I am receiving post Unmarshal is empty in my code, and contains empty QueryParm struct pointers in the playground.  The JSON string clearly exists beforehand.

```
Parms: [{"ColumnName":"message_property_assetId","ColumnType":"string"},{"ColumnName":"id","ColumnType":"string"},{"ColumnName":"message_id","ColumnType":"string"},{"ColumnName":"message_security_tenantId","ColumnType":"string"}]
Type: string
Parms: [   ]
Type: []*proto_export.QueryParm
```

Is there some reason why the output from my code and the playground should differ?

**CONCLUSION EDIT:**

I wanted to say that for some strange reason, I was using a different struct to encode my JSON than I was to decode it.  This caused the JSON field names to be different and prevented the JSON from being decoded properly.

Make sure you use the same struct to encode as you do to decode!

Comment: The `QueryParm` fields are not set in the playground example because  the JSON field tag names do no match the JSON. Example: The field `ColumnName` has json tag `column_name`.  There is no field with that name in the JSON.

Comment: Not that this is the problem, but the expression `d.QueryParms == *new(string)` can be written more simply as `d.QueryParms == ""`.

Comment: The output for the non-playground case is what I would expect when decoding fails.  Does `createJobResponse` return an error?

Comment: @CeriseLimón You are correct, the playground case doesn't set the fields properly, but it does hold the empty QueryParm Object pointers where the code example doesnt't the field's not being set seems to be a protobuff issue that I will need to investigate.  The non-playground case does not return an error, and doesn't hold pointers to empty QueryParm objects.  Am I to understand that this should be normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two working solutions:

1. You may use:

```
var qp []interface{}
```

Try [this](https://goplay.space/#RXoRzumWBJQ):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type QueryParm struct {
    ColumnName           string   `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=column_name,json=columnName,proto3" json:"column_name,omitempty"`
    ColumnType           string   `protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=column_type,json=columnType,proto3" json:"column_type,omitempty"`
    WhereValue           string   `protobuf:"bytes,3,opt,name=where_value,json=whereValue,proto3" json:"where_value,omitempty"`
    XXX_NoUnkeyedLiteral struct{} `json:"-"`
    XXX_unrecognized     []byte   `json:"-"`
    XXX_sizecache        int32    `json:"-"`
}

func main() {
    jsonstr := `[
        {"ColumnName":"message_property_assetId","ColumnType":"string"},
        {"ColumnName":"id","ColumnType":"string"},
        {"ColumnName":"message_id","ColumnType":"string"},
        {"ColumnName":"message_security_tenantId","ColumnType":"string"}]`
    // var qp []QueryParm
    var qp []interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonstr), &qp); err != nil {
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(qp)
}
```

Output:

```
[map[ColumnName:message_property_assetId ColumnType:string] map[ColumnName:id ColumnType:string] map[ColumnName:message_id ColumnType:string] map[ColumnName:message_security_tenantId ColumnType:string]]
```

---

2. You have `column_name` and `column_type` not `ColumnName` and `ColumnType` in your JSON tag: `json:"column_name,omitempty"` so you may change your input string, e.g.:

```
    jsonstr := `[
    {"column_name":"message_property_assetId","column_type":"string"},
    {"column_name":"id","column_type":"string"},
    {"column_name":"message_id","column_type":"string"},
    {"column_name":"message_security_tenantId","column_type":"string"}]`
```

Try [this](https://goplay.space/#gn9nMJsTOxv):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type QueryParm struct {
    ColumnName           string   `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=column_name,json=columnName,proto3" json:"column_name,omitempty"`
    ColumnType           string   `protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=column_type,json=columnType,proto3" json:"column_type,omitempty"`
    WhereValue           string   `protobuf:"bytes,3,opt,name=where_value,json=whereValue,proto3" json:"where_value,omitempty"`
    XXX_NoUnkeyedLiteral struct{} `json:"-"`
    XXX_unrecognized     []byte   `json:"-"`
    XXX_sizecache        int32    `json:"-"`
}

func main() {
    jsonstr := `[
        {"column_name":"message_property_assetId","column_type":"string"},
        {"column_name":"id","column_type":"string"},
        {"column_name":"message_id","column_type":"string"},
        {"column_name":"message_security_tenantId","column_type":"string"}]`
    var qp []QueryParm
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonstr), &qp); err != nil {
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", qp)
}
```

Output:

```
[{ColumnName:message_property_assetId ColumnType:string WhereValue: XXX_NoUnkeyedLiteral:{} XXX_unrecognized:[] XXX_sizecache:0} {ColumnName:id ColumnType:string WhereValue: XXX_NoUnkeyedLiteral:{} XXX_unrecognized:[] XXX_sizecache:0} {ColumnName:message_id ColumnType: WhereValue: XXX_NoUnkeyedLiteral:{} XXX_unrecognized:[] XXX_sizecache:0} {ColumnName:message_security_tenantId ColumnType:string WhereValue: XXX_NoUnkeyedLiteral:{} XXX_unrecognized:[] XXX_sizecache:0}]
```

---

3. You may write your Custom JSON Marshalling and Unmarshalling.

Comment: The QueryParm struct is generated by protoc, I have added the protofile message to my question, should I believe that this is an issue/bug with protoc?

Comment: No, you can use multiple JSON tag with a third party and Custom JSON Marshalling and UnMarshalling, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38809137/golang-multiple-json-tag-names-for-one-field)

Comment: See the new edit with `var qp []interface{}` without changing your input string.

Comment: I feel pretty stupid now... I was wondering why my JSON was incorrect..  It seems I was using a different struct to encode than to decode... Thanks +1 and I have accepted your answer!