# One struct multiple json representation

Tags: go, struct

The Problem I am trying to solve is that I have a representation as below:

```
type Request struct{
ItId string `form:"itId"`
tR string `form:"treason"`
cd string `form:"cdetails"`
}
```

but I want the above one in such a manner that it can accept:

```
itId and ItrId   both for ItId
```

It will be something like this:

```
type Request struct{
ItId string `form:"itId"` || ItId string `form:"ItrId"`
tR string `form:"treason"`
cd string `form:"cdetails"`
}
```

what can be the possible solution for such a case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to have a struct with multiple JSON tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37118263/is-it-possible-to-have-a-struct-with-multiple-json-tags)

Comment: Yeah, Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure which package are you importing that uses `form` struct tag, but to try and answer the question, I am assuming it is similar to `json` tag that is imported by `encoding/json` package.

In short, no it is not possible to have a same **struct tag** for a field, as answered in this SOF question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/37118633/5353730

The OP in above question was trying to accomplish something like:

```
type Foo struct {
    Name string `json:"name" json:"employee_name"`
    Age  int    `json:"age" json:"-"`
}
```

...which I assume is what you want to achieve.

If, however, you might've been trying to use different meta tags for the same field, then that is easily supportable as shown in this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/18635910/5353730

```
type Page struct {
    PageId string                 `bson:"pageId" json:"pageId"`
    Meta   map[string]interface{} `bson:"meta" json:"meta"`
}
```

P.S. You can always create 2 separate fields, one each for `itId` and `ItrId` to solve your problem but then you will need to check for both these fields at the place of usage of struct.